# How do I successfully block comment code in VS Code?

Tags: python

I am a newish python coder using VS Code and whenever I want to block comment using the '''...''' or """...""" and putting sample output within the quotes I get an error:

```
PS C:\Users\chris\Desktop\CMPSC\Week 11>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\chris\Desktop\CMPSC\Week 11'; &
'c:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe'
'c:\Users\chris\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '54083' '--' 'c:\Users\chris\Desktop\CMPSC\Week 11\HW8.py'   
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 6-7: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I went to IDLE and everything ran fine with the block comments so I was wondering if anyone had a similar issue with VS and solved it.(Also note: I am doing this because it is for a class and we have to include sample output!)

Comment: Docstrings aren't comments in the usual "ignored by the parser" sense of things at all. You want a `#` at the front of each commented out line. Don't use multi-line strings when you need comments; don't use comments when you need multi-line strings.

Comment: Python doesn't have multiline/block comments, so using multiple regular line comments (`#`) might be what you want. That should be the editor behavior when you highlight multiple lines and use the 'comment' shortcut. But, suppose you _do_ want to use strings in this case instead of a comment, try using a raw string instead by prefixing it with `r` like: `r"""..."""` This will prevent Python from trying to interpret escape sequences that may be occurring in your literal string.